# MVC Visual Studio - Login

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I am using Azure to host my database and I was wondering how I could re-use the built in login system that is provided in an MVC 5 project.  Our current stack is Database -> entity -> serviceController -> client -> controller(that uses a client) -> view.  The built in database is local and I don't understand how it works well enough to modify it for our purpose.

I don't need complete instructions but just a general idea of what I can re-use and how I would go about finding that would be greatly helpful.

My basic goal is to copy the table entries that are default and use them in my own database.  I can deal with the models and controllers in any way that will work, I'm okay breaking from our current stack to get this prototyped at least.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help, I'm just really lost at how to connect this to our table.

Comment: So if I want to reuse the login system that is there, which parts of the database need to be copied to the new database? there is a lot of stuff there and I don't think that I need ALL of it.  Once I have the database, what can I change to redirect to the model, currently I just use the connection string to our database to connect to our model but I don't see anything like that for the local database the program uses by default so I don't know how to change which of the 2 tables it connects to (assuming I coped everything correctly in the first place)

Comment: I hate to ask a question that is this vague but Ive spent a lot of time stuck and this is due soon and I'm holding my group from completing it so I'm kind of desperate.